# How does my randomly partitioned array look in the general case?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

1. I have an array of n random integers
2. I choose a random integer and partition by the chosen random integer (all integers smaller than the chosen integer will be on the left side, all bigger integers will be on the right side)

What will be the size of my left and right side in the average case, if we assume no duplicates in the array?

I can easily see, that there is 1/n chance that the array is split in half, if we are lucky. Additionally, there is 1/n chance, that the array is split so that the left side is of length 1/2-1 and the right side is of length 1/2+1 and so on.

Could we derive from this observation the "average" case?

Comment: The average size is n/2. Each element of the array is equally likely to be chosen as the pivot. So the size is a uniform distribution from 0 to n.

Comment: Are you trying to analyze the average case of QuickSort? Motwani–Raghavan and Mitzenmacher–Upfal should have coverage of that.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat exactly, that's why I'm thinking after choosing randomly an integer, how will the arrays be partitioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably find a better explanation (and certainly the proper citations) in a textbook on randomized algorithms, but here's the gist of average-case QuickSort, in two different ways.

### First way

Let C(n) be the expected number of comparisons required on average for a random permutation of 1...n. Since the expectation of the sum of the number of comparisons required for the two recursive calls equals the sum of the expectations, we can write a recurrence that averages over the n possible divisions:

```
C(0) = 0

             1 n−1
C(n) = n−1 + ― sum (C(i) + C(n−1−i))
             n i=0
```

Rather than pull the exact solution out of a hat (or peek at the second way), I'll show you how I'd get an asymptotic bound.

First, I'd guess the asymptotic bound. Obviously I'm familiar with QuickSort and my reasoning here is fabricated, but since the best case is O(n log n) by the Master Theorem, that's a reasonable place to start.

Second, I'd guess an actual bound: 100 n log (n + 1). I use a big constant because why not? It doesn't matter for asymptotic notation and can only make my job easier. I use log (n + 1) instead of log n because log n is undefined for n = 0, and 0 log (0 + 1) = 0 covers the base case.

Third, let's try to verify the inductive step. Assuming that C(i) ≤ 100 i log (i + 1) for all i ∈ {0, ..., n−1},

```
             1 n−1
C(n) = n−1 + ― sum (C(i) + C(n−1−i))    [by definition]
             n i=0

             2 n−1
     = n−1 + ― sum C(i)                 [by symmetry]
             n i=0

             2 n−1
     ≤ n−1 + ― sum 100 i log(i + 1)     [by the inductive hypothesis]
             n i=0

               n
             2 /
     ≤ n−1 + ― | 100 x log(x + 1) dx    [upper Darboux sum]
             n /
               0

             2
     = n−1 + ― (50 (n² − 1) log (n + 1) − 25 (n − 2) n)
             n

           [WolframAlpha FTW, I forgot how to integrate]

     = n−1 + 100 (n − 1/n) log (n + 1) − 50 (n − 2)

     = 100 (n − 1/n) log (n + 1) − 49 n + 100.
```

Well that's irritating. It's almost what we want but that + 100 messes up the program a little bit. We can extend the base cases to n = 1 and n = 2 by inspection and then assume that n ≥ 3 to finish the bound:

```
C(n) = 100 (n − 1/n) log (n + 1) − 49 n + 100

     ≤ 100 n log (n + 1) − 49 n + 100

     ≤ 100 n log (n + 1).    [since n ≥ 3 implies 49 n ≥ 100]
```

Once again, no one would publish such a messy derivation. I wanted to show how one could work it out formally without knowing the answer ahead of time.

### Second way

How else can we derive how many comparisons QuickSort does in expectation? Another possibility is to exploit the linearity of expectation by summing over each pair of elements the probability that those elements are compared. What is that probability? We observe that a pair {i, j} is compared if and only if, at the leaf-most invocation where i and j exist in the array, either i or j is chosen as the pivot. This happens with probability 2/(j+1 − i), since the pivot must be i, j, or one of the j − (i+1) elements that compare between them. Therefore,

```
        n    n      2
C(n) = sum  sum  ―――――――
       i=1 j=i+1 j+1 − i

        n  n+1−i 2
     = sum  sum  ―
       i=1  d=2  d

        n
     = sum 2 (H(n+1−i) − 1)           [where H is the harmonic numbers]
       i=1

          n
     = 2 sum H(i) − n
         i=1

     = 2 (n + 1) (H(n+1) − 1) − n.    [WolframAlpha FTW again]
```

Since H(n) is Θ(log n), this is Θ(n log n), as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this answers my question. The 1st method is very simple to understand, the second one is very interesting. Before posting the question, I was actually thinking how to solve it and made some rough sketches. I actually came at some point to the harmonic numbers, but seeing it for the first time, I had no idea how to proceed from there. Thanks!